# Excel VBA Replace is not working with formulas

Tags: excel, vba, replace, excel-formula

I tried to replace a string form value in order to create a formula:

Cell:

```
"XY=(TRIM(CONCATENATE(AH11, AH12)))"
```

Now I am using a classical replace function in VBA:

```
Cells.Replace What:="XY", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
```

When recording this with the macro recorder it works and the formula comes up, but if running again with the macro it does not work.

Does anyone know why?

The whole reason behind this is that I've created a "Formula Creator" which should create a formula based on a dropdown and this is the output of the dropdown concatenation.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen? You're implicitly working off the `ActiveSheet` - it would be good to specify the workbook/worksheet before `Cells`.

Comment: So you can replicate it by having just one sheet and a formula with a string before the "=". Now record a Marco to replace it. It works, but when trying to apply the Macro again it does not work.

Comment: Interesting is though, that I can replace it by any other value. So exchanging XY for YX works, but not XY for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Looks okay at first glance, problem is not immediately obvious.

A few things to try:

1. MatchByte - check out that parameter - on the unlikely possibility that the saved parameter is the cause.
2. Try removing the last argument `FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2` and see what happens
3. Check that "cells" is referring to a range object in your use case (i.e. you or your code are navigated to the expected sheet containing your cell, when this line of your VBA code is reached).
4. Confirm that the substring "XY" is indeed part of your cell value as displayed, not its format. You can do this in VBA by getting e.g. `Range($A$1).value2` (where "$A$1" is the reference of your cell). Or you can do it in excel by, in another cell setting its formula to "=$A$1" and THEN formatting it to general.

Based on your question I would not expect any of these to be the problem but posting here in case it helps troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the following issue:
I recorded a find/replace on my pc, it gave a command with "FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2".  I embedded that in my macro and it worked fine.  I installed my macro on another computer, and the find/replace command caused the macro to abort every time on that computer, even though it worked fine on mine.
On the second computer, I recorded a find/replace and found that it recorded without the "FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2" piece.  So, I removed it from my macro.  Both computers are now working fine.